# jQuery or DOM performance

Tags: jquery, performance, dom

On one of my web-pages, i need to have a list of words, each of which should get a border around it when clicked. When another word is clicked, the previous one looses the border and the new one gets one. I will also need to show a div with some options for the clicked word.

To achieve goal I used jQuery. The idea is simple: to remove a class with no border from the previous element and to add a class with a border to a new one. However, this works painfully slow when the number of such words gets into hundreds. How can i improve that? By the way, it renders slowly, too.

Here is the code i use (without the CSS)

HTML

`...`

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class='invis'>
        <span word="24">YOu are a cool programmer</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

...

JQuery Javascript:

`var currentElement = null;
$('.invis').click(function() {
    if (currentElement != null) {
        currentElement.removeClass("bordered");
        currentElement.addClass("invis");
    }
    $(this).removeClass("invis");
    $(this).addClass("bordered");
    currentElement = $(this);
});`

Comment: Whats with the big amount of html? If based on words instead of collections of words in your example you could probably even do without any pre-wrapping of words. But as a starter I would use only p with a span per word. I don't see the point of the invis classed div. Also I suggest not using jQuery if things turn slow, jQuery can give a huge overhead. No jQuery is not that hard.

Comment: @ReneGeuze: The thing is that i will have to show layers with options for the selected item. The excessive amount of wrappers are a part of the solution i chose (maybe not the best one, will have to look into it).

Comment: And is every list of options different? If they are all the same you can wrap items based on selected index(as tinymce for example does) and add the list to the dom after the click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the culprit was "float:left" for the .invis and .bordered in CSS. Without that it started working significantly faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it the old fashion way without a library, something like:

```
var invis = document.getElementsByClassName('invis'), last=false;

for (var i=0; i<invis.length; i++) {
    invis[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        if (last) last.className = 'invis';
        this.className = 'bordered';
        last=this;
    });
}
```

​

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dXZzY/1/)

Comment: And, how does this help solve the problem?  Also doesn't work in some versions of IE.

Comment: This had the same performance on my HTML and CSS. That's why i started looking for differences in other parts, and found out that the problem was in CSS